# enum in prisma with mysql

Tags: nestjs, prisma

i am working on a nest project and i need to make an assignment model which is using enum and here is the code

```
enter code here
model assignments {
id                        Int                         @id @default(autoincrement())
title                     String?                     @db.VarChar(255)
type                      String?                     @db.VarChar(100)
lesson                    Int?
grade                     Int?
image                     String?                     @db.VarChar(255)
video                     String?                     @db.VarChar(255)
sound                     String?                     @db.VarChar(255)
link                      String?                     @db.VarChar(255)
weight                    Int?
difficulty                Int?
bloom                     Int?
dok                       Int?
duration                  Int?
questions_count           Int?
attempts                  Int?
tags                      String?                     @db.VarChar(255)
open_date                 String?                     @db.VarChar(100)
close_date                String?                     @db.VarChar(100)
cutoff_date               String?                     @db.VarChar(100)
extend_date               String?                     @db.VarChar(100)
non_graded                Boolean?
description               String?                     @db.VarChar(255)
questions_type            assignments_questions_type? @default(Random)
active                    Int?                        @default(1) @db.TinyInt
is_quiz                   Int?                        @default(0) @db.TinyInt
weights                   weights?                    @relation(fields: [weight], 
references: [id], onDelete: Restrict, onUpdate: Restrict, map: "weight")
assignments_has_questions assignments_has_questions[]
sequences_lessons         sequences_lessons[]
submissions               submissions[]

@@index([weight], map: "weight")
 }

enum assignments_questions_type {
Specific 
Random
}
```

so when i run my project it gets this error

[Nest] 7380  - 05/15/2023, 6:09:27 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enumTypes')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enumTypes')

it seems like it cant handle the enum type but in the prisma docs i found it like what i made and mysql support enums so i need to know where is the problem